# Rails : launch Yarn build in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, docker-compose, yarnpkg

I'm working on a Rails 5.1.4 application, and I just added Webpack/Yarn to start working with TypeScript.

I want to compile multiple TypeScript files into one app.js file, which is included in my layout.

Locally, I'm working in a docker-compose setup. A webpack-dev-server is launched with my local web server, everything is working fine.

In my staging, the compilation of the app.js is working fine.

My problem is in the test environment. I can't run my specs locally anymore, I get this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error:
   The asset "bundles/app.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.`

The app.js file is generated by the `yarn build` command. Is there any configuration that would make sure that app.js is compiled in the test environment? And that keep this file up-to-date with the latest Ts code changes?